# XML Schema Regex restriction different lengths

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, schema

I use in my XML schema something like that:

```
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-Z]{3,12}" />
    </xs:restriction>
```

Now I want my string not to have a length BETWEEN 3 and 12 but the length 3 OR 12.. Furthermore I want to check if the string has the length 3, 4, 6 or 12..

Thank you for your help!!

Kind regards

Comment: If valid strings have length 3 or length 12, what does it mean to check whether they have length 4 or 6?  Or do you mean that you want the validator to issue a special message when a string has length 4 or 6, distinct from the message it issues when the string has length 5?

Answer (score 3):

> Furthermore I want to check if the string has the length 3, 4, 6 or 12..

```
^([A-Za-z]{12}|[A-Za-z]{6}|[A-Za-z]{3,4})$
```

OR

```
"([A-Za-z]{12}|[A-Za-z]{6}|[A-Za-z]{3,4})"
```

Comment: Thank you! "([A-Z0-9]{12}|[A-Z0-9]{6}|[A-Z0-9]{3,4})" worked fine.